# how to connect config to env file correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and updating a project where config file is setup up based on env file.

I changed the env file according to template. But cnofig somehow can not find the env variables.

This is my config code:

```
import _tr from 'transenv'
const transenv = _tr.default

export default transenv()(({str, num, bool}) => {
  const env = str('NODE_ENV', 'development')
  const isDev = env === 'development'

  return {
    env,
    isDev,
    port: str('PORT'),
    db: {
      connectionString: str('DB_CONNECTION_STRING'),
    },
    emsKey: str('EMS_KEY'),
  }
})
```

This is my env file:

```
# Example configuration file, copy this file to .env and change your settings
PORT=8000

# Db connection
DB_CONNECTION_STRING=database://name:password@server:port/database

# EMS
EMS_KEY=FAKE_EMS_KEY
```

I am getting error:

```
Error: Missing env: PORT
Missing env: DB_CONNECTION_STRING
Missing env: EMS_KEY
```

Where can be the problem. I was not sure about saving the env file but chose .env as name and All_files as type and in file explorer its written .env and ENV file on it, so hope that is not the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could get your env data from .env file using
`process.env.PORT`

I recommend using **dotenv** in your projects

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add another dev dependency I would strongly recommend [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for working with environment variables.